# how to revert back after generate an controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using **Rails v2.3.2**

I generate a controller by:

```
script/generate controller cars
```

It will create many directories and files:

```
  exists  app/controllers/
  exists  app/helpers/
  create  app/views/cars
  create  test/functional/
  create  test/unit/helpers/
  create  app/controllers/cars_controller.rb
  create  test/functional/cars_controller_test.rb
  create  app/helpers/cars_helper.rb
  create  test/unit/helpers/cars_helper_test.rb
```

**Two questions:**

**1.** How can I **revert** this command back?(What is the command to revert it back)?

**2** What is the command if I **only want** to generate `app/controllers/cars_controller.rb` **without** other files and directories been generated?

Comment: If you want to ask 2 questions, do just that: ask 2 questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either should work

```
    rails destroy controller cars  #rails 3

    script/destroy controller cars #rails 2
```

And if you want to just create a controller file, you might as well create a new file and rename it to cars_controller.rb .

Answer (score 2):

Another solution could be:

- Ensure that you have a version management in place (Git, Subversion, anything working).
- Ensure that you have an updated current working copy, with no pending changes.
- Then you can revert your changes by using your version management. In Subversion, you would just call `svn revert .` in the Rails application root directory.

Comment: +1 for the "VCS handles this". I'll refrain the -1 for using `svn` as an example, where `git` is so definitely superior (this is a deliberate troll :))

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 rails destroy controller cars or script/destroy controller cars
```

and for models

```
rails destroy model blahblah
```

if you want to generate without test files try using this option

```
script/generate controller cars -T
```

and if you want to leave out helper files follow this [tutorial](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/72-remove-empty-helpers)

Answer (score 0):

Two answers

1. `script/destroy controller cars #rails 2`
2. `script/generate controller -T --[skip|no]-views --[skip|no]-helper`

Where you can use either `skip` or `no` as a prefix